# Leading whitespaces in makefile variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to declare a makefile variable with a leading white space, and I used the following code, but it doesn't work

```
SPACE :=
SPACE +=
VIU_DIAG_SW_VERSION :=$(SPACE)AJ
```

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem.  Why do you need to declare a variable with leading space in its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
NULL :=
VIU_DIAG_SW_VERSION := $(NULL) AJ
```

Demo:

```
$ cat Makefile
NULL :=
VIU_DIAG_SW_VERSION := $(NULL) AJ

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo "X$(VIU_DIAG_SW_VERSION)X"
$ make
X AJX
```

And if you want a variable containing just one space:

```
SPACE := $(NULL) $(NULL)
```

Comment: `SPACE := $(strip) $(strip)` also works, or with some other built-in function.

Comment: You're right. Any token expanding as an empty string works: `SPACE := $(eval) $(call)` or `SPACE := $(info) $(foreach)` also work. But I personally prefer an explicit name like `NULL`, I find it easier to read.

Comment: Barely related information: "Make 4.3 will only add a space when += is used if the variable it is used on exists. Using += on a non-existing variable would previously create a variable starting with a space." - [https://linuxreviews.org/GNU_make_4.3_Is_Released]